# Windows 8.1 Wampserver Mysql won't run

Tags: mysql, wampserver, windows-8.1

i installed Windows 8.1 then i re-install wampserver and everything was working .. till i get a orange color that due to my MySQL server not running ....

Wampserver 2.4

MySQL 5.6.12

PHP 5.4.12

Apache 2.4.4

this is the log file

```
2013-12-18 10:00:00 904 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2013-12-18 10:00:00 904 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2013-12-18 10:00:00 904 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2013-12-18 10:00:00 904 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2013-12-18 10:00:00 904 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions
2013-12-18 10:00:00 904 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
2013-12-18 10:00:00 904 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2013-12-18 10:00:00 904 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2013-12-18 10:00:00 904 [Note] InnoDB: The log sequence numbers 2283844 and 2283844 in ibdata files do not match the log sequence number 2484632 in the ib_logfiles!
2013-12-18 10:00:00 904 [Note] InnoDB: Database was not shutdown normally!
2013-12-18 10:00:00 904 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
2013-12-18 10:00:00 904 [Note] InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
2013-12-18 10:00:00 904 [ERROR] InnoDB: Attempted to open a previously opened tablespace. Previous tablespace airbnb/amenities uses space ID: 6 at filepath: .\airbnb\amenities.ibd. Cannot open tablespace webotrip/amenities which uses space ID: 6 at filepath: .\webotrip\amenities.ibd
InnoDB: Error: could not open single-table tablespace file .\webotrip\amenities.ibd
InnoDB: We do not continue the crash recovery, because the table may become
InnoDB: corrupt if we cannot apply the log records in the InnoDB log to it.
InnoDB: To fix the problem and start mysqld:
InnoDB: 1) If there is a permission problem in the file and mysqld cannot
InnoDB: open the file, you should modify the permissions.
InnoDB: 2) If the table is not needed, or you can restore it from a backup,
InnoDB: then you can remove the .ibd file, and InnoDB will do a normal
InnoDB: crash recovery and ignore that table.
InnoDB: 3) If the file system or the disk is broken, and you cannot remove
InnoDB: the .ibd file, you can set innodb_force_recovery > 0 in my.cnf
InnoDB: and force InnoDB to continue crash recovery here.
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

i found a solution

1. Backup your \wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.6.12\data folder JUST IN CASE.
2. left click the wampmanager icon -> MySQL -> my.ini ( to edit the mysql config file )

and add this line to the wampmysqld section [wampmysqld] (or [mysqld] if You don't have [wampmysqld])

innodb_force_recovery = 1

and then save my.ini

3. left click the wampmanager icon -> MySQL -> Service -> restart service

give it a minute to do its recovery, then check the mysql error log again to see if it has recovered the database.

4. left click the wampmanager icon -> MySQL -> my.ini ( to edit the mysql config file )

now remove the innodb_force_recovery = 1 parameter you previously added.

Comment: on windows 8.1 fully updated i have the same problem after i shutdown the pc and start it again the mysql hits me with the same error. anything i would do doesn't work.

Comment: haven't tested it yet http://www.teceek.com/how-to-solve-mysql-server-error-in-xampp-windows-8-1/ but it looks promising.

Comment: This worked for me:
**Stick with the 32 bit.**

Uninstall the 64bit and make sure you then DELETE the mysql-data folder and all its subfolders before installing the 32 bit.

(Source: http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,125883,printview,page=1)